# Cookie recognized for example.com but not to www.example.com

Tags: php, cookies

I'm using the following code to create a cookie:

```
function createSession($userid,$firstname)
{
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    setcookie("usid", $userid, $expire);
    setcookie("usname", $firstname, $expire);
}
```

When I log to my site with the following address: mysite.com the cookie is recognized but when I log with this address: www.mysite.com the cookie isn't recognized, why?

I'm using the following code to check if the cookie exists:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['usid']))
   $newuser = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a domain parameter to setcookie(), look at  http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

What you want is

```
setcookie("usid", $userid, $expire, "/", ".mysite.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a DNS reccored so your website is forwarded from example.com to www.example.com. Or just put it in your .htaccess file of your website.